# What happens to the first puppy in A Dog's Purpose?

Tags: a-dogs-purpose

In the beginning of [A Dog's Purpose](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1753383/?ref_=nv_sr_2), a small puppy is shown to be captured and the narrator says

> And then it was over.

While the human says

> That's it for you.

Did the puppy just get captured and killed by a pound? What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *implied* that he was killed by the pound but of course we don't see it happen

> In the 1950s, a feral puppy named Toby is whisked away to the dog pound and quickly **euthanized**, wondering if "fun" truly is life's purpose.
>
> His strong spirit is **reborn** and reincarnated as a newborn Retriever puppy in 1961,
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dog%27s_Purpose_(film))</sup>